# how to implement google maps v3 in flex action script

Tags: actionscript-3, google-maps, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4.5

HI i want to implement GoogleMaps js v3 in flex i read almost most of the tutorial none of them are helpful to me. Can any one share me a working piece of code which can be helpful for me please

Answer (score 0):

GoogleMaps ActionSCript API is already stopped and now its not available. If you want to develop than you have to develop using JavaScript and you need to call JavaSCript Based Application which will be called from Flex Application using External Interface.

Best Idea, you have to develop one JavaScript Based Application which will load your swf file (flex application compiled version) and when ever user will click for Map than you need to hide flex application and on top of it you need to open GoogleMap JavaScript Application.

For JavaScript Application development you can use Angular.js or other similar framework.